# how to fix Warning: split() [function.split]: REG_EBRACK when using split() php

Tags: php, split

I have a string that I am trying to split

```
$str = "/5/75/1909/[]valle_real";
```

trying to split it like this

```
$level3 = split('[]',$str);
```

But its showing warning

> Warning:  split() [function.split]: REG_EBRACK in line above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$level3 = split('\[\]',$str);
```

But [`split` is depricated](http://php.net/manual/de/function.split.php)! What you probably want is either [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php) or [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php), which are not depricated.

The reason btw. is, that `[` and `]` have a special meaning in regexes and `split` expects the first parameter to be a regex.

Comment: thanks ill except your answer in 10 min :) , SO what should I use ?

Comment: `explode` in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$level3 = explode('\[\]',$str);
```

Comment: The first parameter must be `'[]'` because `explode` (unlike `split`) does not expect the first parameter to be a regex

Comment: True!
In fact, during edit, I have forgotten to edit argument:

`$level3 = explode('[]',$str);`